# How enforceable is a TA10 after exchange and completion

Tags: united-kingdom, property

When a homeowner sells a house in the UK, they fill out a [TA10 Law Society Fittings and Contents form](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/support-services/advice/articles/ta-form-specimens/).

This details which items within the property are included, excluded or for sale at an additional price.

When exchanging the TA10 becomes apart of the contract.

My question is, how enforceable is that form in terms of those items that are included. If an item is ticked as included, with no additional cost associated, and no comments outlined, is the seller able to invoice the buyer for those items after completion.

If the seller was to try and invoice for items ticked as included, is the buyer protected and not required to pay.

Answer (score 1):

An invoice such as this would not be enforceable since you have proof of ownership through the completion contract and associated documents. They can't sell to you what you already own therefore this invoice should be treated as speculative and not paid.

Unfortunately if they complete the form as to show items would be included in the sale, but do not leave them in the property this is more complicated. Technically you own them and they have stolen them. If you wish them to be returned this should be reported to the Police. You would be unlikely to win a civil claim for the value of the items removed since their removal was not legal in the first place.